# How to find the nearest parent when inserting Node?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following text:

> Hi, `<span class='blue_mark'>`my name is Bob`</span>`.

Let's say I want to highlight **Bob** with a `.red_mark`. When I do this, the nearest parent would be `.blue_mark` and not the main parent. I want to calculate this because I don't want any spans nested inside of each other. Only from the main parent.

This is my code:

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  var contents = range.extractContents();
  var node = document.createElement('span');
  node.classList.add('blue_mark');
  node.appendChild(contents);
  range.insertNode(node);
  selection.removeAllRanges(); //Clear the selection, showing highlight
```

Before I insertNode, I want to check if the span is nested inside another span. If so, don't insert and have an alert come up. If not, then insert the content/

Comment: You refer to a term "main parent", but it's not clear what that is or how it's different than an actual DOM node's parent.

Comment: Show more HTML context for both cases when insert would be OK and when Ashley should be raised

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you don't want to have any overlapping spans. So:

1. The start of the selection can't be inside a span
2. The end of the selection can't be inside a span
3. The selection cannot fully contain a span

First, a utility function:

```
function isInSpan(node) {
    if (node && node.nodeType === 3) {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    while (node && node.nodeType === 1) {
        if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "SPAN") {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, I believe you can check those like this:

```
if (isInSpan(range.startContainer) ||
    isInSpan(range.endContainer) ||
    range.cloneContents().querySelector("span")) {
    // Do the alert
} else {
    // Go ahead and create the span
}
```

(Was pleasantly surprised to see `querySelector` on `DocumentFragment`.)

Comment: Have to disappear, so marking this a CW in case there are queries I'm not around to answer and others want to step in...